# Get all data from parent record as the child record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table as below which has a relationship between the requestID and PrimaryRequestID:

```
RequestID   PrimaryRequestID    Prefix  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1           NULL            MyPrefix
2           1               NULL
```

What I want to do is join this so I get the following output:

```
1   NULL    MyPrefix
2   1       MyPrefix
```

I've tried several joins, but I still end up with a NULL prefix.

Edit: This is probably as close as I've gotten:

```
SELECT  
    ra.RequestID 
    ,CASE WHEN rb.Prefix IS NULL THEN ra.Prefix ELSE ra.Prefix END AS Prefix
FROM requests ra
LEFT  JOIN requests rb on ra.RequestID = rb.PrimaryRequestID
```

Comment: what have you tried?  It is helpful to show your work because you might just need a little push in the right direction on what you have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select S.RequestId, S.PrimaryRequestID, coalesce(P.Prefix, S.Prefix) As Prefix
from myTable P
right join myTable S on P.RequestID = S.PrimaryRequestID
```

Comment: End up with NULL requestID for child records

Comment: (Fixed typos) Not with a **right** join - you get NULL as the PrimaryRequestID on Primary request records, as shown in your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the trick

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (RequestID INT,PrimaryRequestID INT,Prefix VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1,NULL,'MyPrefix'),
    (2,1,NULL)
```

**The query**

```
;WITH CTE(RequestID,PrimaryRequestID,Prefix)
AS
(
    SELECT
        tbl.RequestID,
        tbl.PrimaryRequestID,
        tbl.Prefix
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.PrimaryRequestID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.RequestID,
        tbl.PrimaryRequestID,
        CTE.Prefix
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
        JOIN CTE
            ON tbl.PrimaryRequestID=CTE.RequestID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
```

I'm using a recursive cte function read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

If you have for example one more line in your table. So your table is like this:

```
1   NULL    MyPrefix
2   1       NULL
3   2       NULL
```

Then the output will still be like this:

```
1   NULL    MyPrefix
2   1       MyPrefix
3   2       MyPrefix
```

Becuase I'm using the parent child relationship in the table.

If you want to have some example. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188427/sql-query-for-parent-child-chain), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471134/how-to-self-join-recursively-in-sql), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508762/is-this-possible-in-sql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503274/hierarchical-query-in-sql-server-2005) are some examples on stackoverflow

Comment: You're joining a CTE from within itself? I've never seen that done.

Comment: No problem.. Yeah. This functions are quit useful when you have a parent child relation in the table.

Comment: Yeah, I've learned something from your code which I will read into, but I'm afraid Mark Bannister get's marked as answer as simplicity must prevail :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   c.requestID, 
         c.primaryRequestID, 
         isnull(c.Prefix, p.Prefix)
from     table p, 
         table c
where    c.primaryRequestID   *= p.RequestID
```

Apologies for archaic join syntax....

Comment: this is the same answer as the chosen answer except you are not using outer join as you should (coalesce and isnull does the same thing except coalesce can take more parameters)

Comment: Syntax is valid for oracle, not mssql